# WEB API: How to pass value from ActionFilter to Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have `ActionFilter` to get some values from Request Header. Then I store them in `Request.Properties` like this:

```
actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("technician", username);
actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("secret", secret);
```

Now I want to get this values in my `TaskRepository`.

My Controller Constructor:

```
public TaskController(ITaskRepository repository)  
{
    _repository = repository;
}
```

I can't get properties here, because `ActionFilters` are executing when controller has been already chosen and created.

I can get properties in Controller's every action and pass them to repository, but I thnik it isn't correct way.

My question is how to pass values from `ActionFilter` to `Repository` ?

Thank you, for your time.

Comment: Why do you want to pass values from filter to repository?

Comment: I am writting REST API for another REST services and I want have some values for all actions. ( This values need to retrive data. ) For e.g. I want to get all tasks for 'technician'. I can add argument in each action, but I think sending it in header more correct way.

Comment: I believe you should create a wrapper around `HttpContextBase` in way it can be injected into any controller - that solution enables you to access request properties and headers(with your "technician" and "secret" data) in `TaskRepository`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finnaly made it.

For first I write `Extension` method for `IHTTPController` like this:

```
public static void SetCredentialsToRepository(this IHttpController controller, string technician, string secret);
```

Then I implement this function like this:

```
public void SetCredentialsToRepository(string technician, string secret)
{
    _repository.SetCredentials(technician, secret);
}
```

And then in my ActionFilter I call this method:

```
actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller.SetCredentialsToRepository(username, secret);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do something very similar in a ASP.NET Core API and this helped tremendously!